# Android Custom TabLayout: Icon overlays content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

I'm looking for a custom `TabLayout`. The icon of the `Tab` in the middle needs a margin to overlay the content. Please check out the image below.

[image: TabLayout with overlaying icon]

#### What I've tried so far

- `Tab.setCustomView()` with a margin. That doesn't overlay the content though.
- Looked for TabLayout libraries that give such flexibility. Didn't find anything that fits my need.

#### Re-invent the wheel?

Since I don't need any complicated scrolling functionality, I could develop my own TabLayout with a couple `ViewGroups`,`TextView` and `ImageView`. Before I have to do that:

- Do you know of any library that would do that?
- How would you approach it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Thimoli did you find any solution?

Comment: @Tom: I just built a custom view. It's no ideal solution. I'd share the solution as a library, but it's not generic enough.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved that by the combination of a custom library and the floating action button.
The library: [MagicIndicator on GitHub](https://github.com/hackware1993/MagicIndicator)

I set the icon of the middle fragment to an empty icon and positioned the floating action button in the middle to overlay the TabLayout. It looks like this:
[image]
My activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_behavior" />

<net.lucode.hackware.magicindicator.MagicIndicator
    android:id="@+id/magic_indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_icon"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```